# aspx page Text Box with placeholder. How do I format the Css of the placeholder?

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

Please see aspx page below, I have a text box that I am trying to italicize the placeholder text. Do I use css? I've never really used so if so please show with example. Thanks!

```
  <asp:TextBox ID ="txtMyTextBox" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" MaxLength="30" Width="115px" placeholder="Text Box"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: `font-style: italic;`, It will stay italic when text is entered. If you need it to change you'll need a little JS to change it. There are examples of that online (and probably here on SO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to style the place holder of your textbox control. Follow this format to structure it:

```
::placeholder {
  /* your css declarations; */
}
```

And if you want to style different textboxes differently, you can add styles like below to your textbox.

```
<style>
  .MyTextBox::placeholder {
    color:red;
    font-style: italic; /*I see you needed an example for italic text*/
  }
</style>

<asp:TextBox ID ="txtMyTextBox"
     runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" 
     MaxLength="30" Width="115px" 
     CssClass="MyTextBox" 
     placeholder="Text Box">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Working Example:

```css
.MyTextBox::placeholder {
  color:red;
  font-style: italic; /*I see you needed an example for italic text*/
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="MyTextBox" placeholder="Hello World"/>
```

---

For IE 10-11:

```
.MyTextBox:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jamshaid Kamran! This example was perfect and helped me realize what I was missing since I am not use to Css. The only thing I had to change was the placeholder selector that is used in IE 11.

Comment: Happy to be of help. I have updated for IE 10-11 as well.